# What is the use of "export" command?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I created a environment  variable in one terminal window and tried to echo it in another terminal window. That displayed nothing.

```
$TEST=hello
```

After that I exported it and tried again to `echo` it in a different terminal window. result was same as before.

```
export TEST
```

but if I execute the same code at the login (appending the code to `~/.profile` file) variables can be used any terminal window. What is happening here? What is the different between executing a code in a terminal and executing the same at the login?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`export` makes a variable something that will be included in child process environments.  It does not affect other already existing environments.  In general there isn't a way to set a variable in one terminal and have it automatically appear in another terminal, the environment is established for each process on its own.

Adding it to your `.profile` makes it so that your environment will be setup to include that new variable each time you log in though.  So it's not being exported from one shell to another, but instead is instructing a new shell to include it when it sets up the initial environment.

Answer (score 1):

Each process has several attributes that the process can set individually and independently from other processes. Examples are resource limits, umask, current directory, environment variables and some more. Upon process creation (by way of the `fork()` system call) the child inherits these attributes from the parent. After this the child process may set these attributes arbitrarily. (Some restrictions apply, a process may not increase hard resource limits or change its current directory to a directory for which it has no exec permission.)

Only few programs modify their environment variables, most don't bother. Suppose the latter case. So if a child process creates itself further children, then these processes will have the same environment variables as the grandparent. And so on.

Now, a shell has a lot of variables that can be viewed with `set` (in shells of Bourne Shell type, dunno about C Shell). These variables are not environment variables unless they are `export`ed. Environment variables can be viewed with `env`. If you launch a program from the shell command line, the program will inherit the environment variables from the shell. Likewise for a program launched from a shell script.

Therefore, upon login there is a shell that reads profile data (e.g. `~/.profile`) and inherits them to virtually all children, grandchildren and so on. This is how environment variable settings trickle down from the login shell or login script to all other programs launched within the login session.

> I created a environment variable in one terminal window and tried to echo it in another terminal window. That displayed nothing.

By the above explanation, this is the expected result. Changes in the environment of a process affects only children of this process that are created henceforth, not existing ones.

> `$TEST=hello`

This is unlikely to work anyway, unless variable expansion is disabled or `$TEST` has already a suitable value. If you want to assign `hello` to variable `TEST` then you have to say `TEST=hello` (note: no `$`).

> After that I exported it and tried again to `echo` it in a different terminal window. result was same as before.

Once again, this is the expected result.

> but if I execute the same code at the login (appending the code to `~/.profile` file) variables can be used any terminal window.

This is because the shell in the terminal is a descendant of the shell that read the environment settings from `~/.profile` and thus inherited these settings.